# PDF for MixtureDistribution fails in Dataset Query in 11.1

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions, dataset

I have the results of a process involving `FindDistribution` as a `Dataset` of probability distributions. Attempting to plot the `PDF`s of these from `Dataset` I kept getting failures. I eventually narrowed this down to the `MixtureDistribution`s.  A minimal example follows.

```
ds = Dataset@<|
   1 -> MixtureDistribution[{.2, .8}, {UniformDistribution[{-.08, 3. 10^6}], 
         GammaDistribution[.5, 88 10^4]}],
   2 -> ExponentialDistribution[1 10^-6]
   |>
```

Attempt to create a `Dataset` of PDF plots from `Dataset` `Query` fails.

```
ds[All,
 With[{pdf = PDF[#, x]},
   Plot[pdf, {x, 0, Quantile[#, .95]}]
   ] &
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Attempt to create list of PDF plots outside of `Dataset` `Query` succeeds.

```
With[{pdf = PDF[ds[#], x]},
   Plot[pdf, {x, 0, Quantile[ds[#], .95]}]
   ] & /@ Range[2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Quantile` succeeds in the query,

```
ds[All, Quantile[#, .95] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but `PDF` fails,

```
ds[All, PDF[#, x] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This was narrowed to the `MixtureDistribution` (first row in `Dataset` and first in list).

```
ds[#, PDF[#, x] &] & /@ Range[2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Remove the `MixtureDistribution` and the `Query` succeeds.

```
ds2 = Dataset@<|
   1 -> NormalDistribution[],
   2 -> ExponentialDistribution[1 10^-6]
   |>;

ds2[All,
 With[{pdf = PDF[#, x]},
   Plot[pdf, {x, 0, Quantile[#, .95]}]
   ] &
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May someone confirm.
Mma 11.1 , Win 7 Ent

CASE: **3866316**

Comment: Same on Linux; workaround `Dataset[Map[PDF[#, x] &, ds // Normal]]` ?

Comment: Reported to WRI.

Answer (score 4):

There are three possible solutions imo to the problem:

### General Advice:  Use `Datatset` to display results only

This was already mentioned by @b.gatessucks in his comment and in [(87360)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87360/764) gives some deeper insights into why working on `Dataset` can sometimes fail unexpectedly. So making `ds` above a simple `Association` will avoid the problem.

As a general recommendation I find it rather robust to avoid `Dataset` for processing data and only use it at the very end to (nicely) present the results. So instead of using `ds[ operator1, operator2, ...]` I will use `ds // Query[ operator1, operator2, ...]` which will work on pretty much anything.

*Edit: Unfortunately in this case the problem is numerical so that only solutions B and C offer a cure. So the former "Solution A" had to be downgraded to general advice.*

### Solution B: Examine the error message and work on it

The error message shown is related to `Reduce` and the message mentioned is [`Reduce::ratnz`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Reduce/ratnz.htm). The documentation will tell you that this has to do with *inexact numbers*. So making `MixtureDistribution` use exact numbers ([`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)) will work:

```
dsExact = Dataset @ Association[ 
    1 -> Rationalize @ MixtureDistribution[ 
             {.2, .8}, 
             { UniformDistribution[{-.08, 3. 10^6}], GammaDistribution[.5, 88 10^4]}
         ],
    2 -> ExponentialDistribution[1 10^-6]
]

dsExact[ All, With[
       {pdf = PDF[#, x]}, Plot[ pdf, {x, 0, Quantile[#, .95]} ]
   ] &
]
```

[image: AOK]

### Solution C: Datasets are very easily 'upset' - so be quiet

```
ds[ All, Quiet @ With[
       {pdf = PDF[#, x]}, Plot[ pdf, {x, 0, Quantile[#, .95]} ]
    ] &
]
```

[image: AOK]

This will work with the OP's `ds` without any problem. So `Dataset` gets *upset* easily by error measages within.

**Edit**

Since Edmund has given a reasonable objection to "quieting" everything (one never knows what) I should mention, that we may as well only quiet the specific message that we do not care about, so

```
Off[ Reduce::ratnz ]

ds[ All, ... ]
```

will work as well.

**Edit2:**

Another way to deal with failure messages is to use the option [`FailureAction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html). So instead of using `Quiet`we may have done:

```
ds[All,
   With[ {pdf = PDF[#, x]},
      Plot[pdf, {x, 0, Quantile[#, .95]}]
   ] &,
   FailureAction -> None 
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the investigations (+1). Solution A is an interesting approach.  Solution B does not work in the real case as the parameter values are not so well behaved as in the minimal working example I provided, the actual distributions are a result of `FindDistribution`.  I'm not too keen on solution C as you never know what you are shushing and it can lead to hard to trace errors.  I think I might use Solution A in this particular case but I like the syntactical sugar of auto-calling `Query` with `Dataset` so I don't see myself dropping that any time soon.

Comment: @Edmund I have edited my answer with regard to the very reasonable objection against Solution C. Using `Off` we very well know what we are "shushing".

Comment: A heads up that solution A gives the same failure result as the Dataset Query: `Normal@ds // 
 Query[All, 
  With[{pdf = PDF[#, x]}, Plot[pdf, {x, 0, Quantile[#, .95]}]] &]` . Currently I'm just mapping and converting like @b.gatessucks comment in the OP.

Comment: @Edmund Ok, I must admit, that I had not checked this more thorouhgly - but it should serve as a general remark in this case. So it is just Solution C : `Off[ Reduce::ratnz ]` which will make this work out.