# EntityFunction for Relational Database error

Tags: entity, databases

I am a student and I am new of Mathematica. 
I am working with relational databases and I am following the guide "Relational Database quick start" find here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RelationalDatabasesQuickStart.html

I have successfully managed to connect to my database. Now I am using the Entity Framework to query my database.

The problem is that I want to pass a global value inside the EntityFunction and not define the column name a priority. I would like to use the code inside a function and pass dynamic parameters to this function.

So this first example works.

```
EntityValue[
  FilteredEntityClass[
   "Customer",
   EntityFunction[e, e["City"] != "Vancuver"]
   ],
  {"FirstName"},
  "PropertyAssociation"
  ] // Dataset
```

But I want to do something like this

```
function[var_,value_] := (
 entity = EntityValue[
  FilteredEntityClass[
   "Customer",
   EntityFunction[e, e[var] != value]
   ],
  {"FirstName"},
  "PropertyAssociation"
  ] // Dataset;
 Return[entity];
);

res = function["City", "Vancouver"];
```

When I try this second solution I get this error

```
EntityFunction::invexpr: The expression e[var] cannot be compiled to SQL.
```

Is it not possible to do something like this?

Comment: Since "Vancuver" is typed by "City" in this relational database there is simply no need for this.

Comment: I modified the code inside the question because perhaps I had not explained myself well. I would like to pass parameters in EntityFunction. In the code shown if I use only "value" as a parameter of the function everything goes correctly, but if I change it and I also have the parameter "var"  I get the error shown. It seem that e[var] is not accepted by Mathematica.

Comment: Your updated example works for me.  You might have some left-over earlier definitions of `function` that are interfering with its operation.  Try re-evaluating its definition after evaluating `ClearAll[function]`.

Comment: It's true it seems you're right. My mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `EntityFunction`, just like `Function`, holds its variable and body, you will have to inject the value into it. This is not specific to `EntityFunction`, and is a common problem of injecting values into held expressions. Just as in other such cases, you can use e.g. `With` to do that:

```
With[{var = "City"},
  EntityValue[
    FilteredEntityClass[
      "Customer",
      EntityFunction[e, e[var] != "Vancuver"]
    ],
    {"FirstName"},
    "PropertyAssociation"
  ] // Dataset
]
```

Comment: FYI, the OP has rewritten the question such that your response no longer applies.

Comment: @WReach Thanks for letting me know. I hate when this happens, feel like a fool :). Anyway, I will keep it around for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable this

[Dataset vw. Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87360/dataset-vs-an-association-of-associations)

sheets sufficient help for the intend of the question. Since the answer there goes deeper than this question it hard to name this question a duplicate. It is too under question whether the shown competence on relational data handling from the questioner is sufficient to understand the answer suggested.

Aside from typing scoping is for sure a possible resolution, change of perspective to this question.