# What's the meaning of TypeSystem`Atom and TypeSystem`Vector?

Tags: core-language

SemanticImport is probably failing to import the data. In fact the log message is transformed into this weird entity.

Dataset[List["Error calling Sogei service http://lb-ven-onl-psqf.winco.local/VenditaPSQF/paymentbetPsqf3Online, error code: 5003 description: Biglietto_non_pagabile_mancano_risultati_ufficiali, \\n Payload: {""header"":{""id_fsc"":99,""id_cn"":15226,""id_pvend"":15226,""goldbet_tag"":0,""tipo_tag"":41,""id_tran"":2147531293,""coupon_code"":""380RU-5RAS7T0T51J7"",""is_test"":false,""id_utente"":561175},""body"":{""aams_ticket_id"":""df07e5091a153488ab04"",""importo"":1150},""ext"":{""info_quota"":null,""id_giocata"":null,""conto_2"":{""id_rete"":14,""id_cn"":15226,""conto"":""561175""}}}","GoldbetServices.Model.Exceptions.MoneyTransactionException: Error during pay bet operation transactionId: 2147483559, amount: 0\\n   at GoldbetServices.Application.Services.BetManager.OnWallBetManager.PayBet(TransactionObjectScope scope, PayCoupon payCoupon) in e:\cruisecontrol\Colibri_sogei_rtm\working\Source\GoldbetServices\GoldbetServices.Application\Services\BetManager\OnWallBetManager.cs:line 495"],TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[String],2],Association[Rule["ID",11205813891157]]]

It should have been a dataset of 1 column with 2 rows of type strig. What is this strange entity? Can I visualize it?

Comment: Can you please include the command you issued (as well)?

Comment: Looks like there was an error retrieving the data so that has to be fixed first. `Error calling Sogei service http://lb-ven-onl-psqf.winco.local/VenditaPSQF/paymentbetPsqf3Online, error code: 5003 description:`

Comment: This does look like a bug in `Dataset`'s error handling, if you can make a self-contained example of the failure you should report it.  The question in the title is best answered by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87479/9490) I think.

Comment: @Syed this is the zipped file: https://we.tl/t-jTRoUP32fG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jose Martin-Garcia explains the Dataset Type System in this video: https://youtu.be/KQeDCEGRjKM?t=600